# What's the need of generics here?

Tags: java, generics, signature

In the following code taken from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) oracle tutorial:

```
public class FileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>
```

is there any need to use generics?. I cannot get this aspect of Generics.
Why would it be fondamental to specify `<Path>`, or better why `SimpleFileVisitor` has been declared in that way? Even better why the designers decided to use generics in this context? In its methods there are Path parameters.. should not it be enough?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my eyes it isn't nessecary to make a big deal of it. Generics are just a helper tool for the compiler. So he can generate a compile error instead of getting a runtime error, that it is hard to dectet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, in its methods there are T parameters, and T being the generic parameter that is passed declared by the class declaration you specified. If, for example, the class declaration looked like this:

```
class AnotherFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<File>
```

the methods would be looking like this:

```
visitFile(File file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

By using

```
SimpleFileVisitor<Path>
```

It is specifying that it takes Path instead of say File.  The methods can't have Path without generics as the SimpleFileVisitor doesn't specify Path.

Answer (score 2):

The class `SimpleFileVisitor` has generic method parameters (e.g. `public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(T file, IOException exc)`).

You are overriding them in FileVisitor, but If there was no generic type used there you would be able to put "Whatherer" as a method parameter and compiler wouldn't argue and having generics you are forced to use the same class as a parameter in overriden methods (in this case `Path`) type in all methods that are defined in `SimpleFileVisitor`.

That's just a matter of clarity and type-safety.